# Find parameters of a gaussian transformation

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-optimization, regression, nonlinear-analysis

I have a system of equations where the relationship between input and output is derived from a pixel lattice:

\begin{equation}
x_i(k+1) = \sum_j \alpha e^{ \frac{\left(dr_{ji}^2 + dc_{ji}^2 \right)}{2 \sigma^2}}  \, x_j(k) 
\end{equation}
where dr_{ji} and dc_{ji} stand for the distance between row and column of pixel $i$ and $j$

In matrix form, this results in
\begin{equation}
x(k+1) = \alpha \, A x(k),
\end{equation}
where, for example, for a 3x3 lattice, A is:

\begin{equation}
A =  \begin{array}{ccccccccc} e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{8}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{8}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{8}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\\ e^\frac{8}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{5}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{2}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{4}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} & e^\frac{0}{2\sigma^2} \end{array}
\end{equation}

I need to find $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ for known x(0) and x(K) vectors that solve the linear system in K steps. This is, perform this linear regression:

\begin{equation}
x(k) = \alpha \, A^K x(0),
\end{equation}

I thought about applying some natural logarithms, but it is not straightforward. Any ideas?

Best